# Rails models association setup to easily render in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations

I have 3 tables and I am trying to figure out the association I need in order to loop through them in a view and output all the necessary fields:

Tbl: blog

- id
- name

tbl: blog_comment_type

- id
- comment_type_id (this is the matching id in the comment_type
  table).

Tbl: comment_type

- id
- name

I am able to loop through the blog_comment_type and get all I need but the one missing field I want to pull is the "name" field from the comment_type table.

```
<% @blog.blog_comment_types.each do |blog_comment_type| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= blog_comment_type.comment_type_id %></td>
      <td>Comment name goes here</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view bit should be straightforward:

> blog_comment_type.comment_type.name

HOWEVER:

I'm guessing you've tried that & it isn't working. Looking at the table, the most likely reason is that the associations between `blogs`, `blog_comment_types`, and `comment_types` aren't established in your models. In short:

- It looks like there's a many to one relationship between `blog_comment_type` and `blog`, but no column responsible for this relationship. Unless I'm misinterpreting, you'll need a `blog_id` field in `blog_comment_type`
- That makes the `blog_comment_type` table just a many-to-many connector between `comment_type` and `blog`.

So, in your blog model you'd want:

```
has_many :blog_comment_types
has_many :comment_types, through: :blog_comment_type
```

In your blog_comment_type model you'd want

```
belongs_to :blog
belongs_to :comment_type
```

And in your comment_type model you'd want

```
has_many :blog_comment_types
has_many :blogs, through: :blog_comment_type
```

With that done, you could put this in your view instead:

```
<%- @blog.comment_types.each do |comment_type| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment_type.id %></td>
    <td><%= comment_type.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Note that you're showing the `comment_type` ID above, not the `blog_comment_type` ID. These *are* different, but I'm pretty sure you want `comment_type id`. `blog_comment_type` table is just a connection between blog & comment type and there's really not much external value to that ID field.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing something there. The structure for `blog_commment_types` should include `blog_id` and `comment_type_id`, leading to this:

```
class BlogCommentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :comment_type
end
```

Then you can use this in a `:through` association:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_comment_types
  has_many :comment_types,
    :through => :blog_comment_types
end
```

Then it's as easy as this:

```
<% @blog.comment_types.each do |comment_type| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment_type.id %></td>
    <td><%= comment_type.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```